# Is there a way to set a timezone for the AVDs launched by Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'd like to add -timezone Europe/London to the command line generated when Android Studio launches an AVD. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a new Run/Debug Config, as under the Emulator tab there is an option for `Additional command line options`, however this would mean leaving the launch of the emulator until I was ready to debug. As the emulators can take a while to load, I tend to launch them from the menu bar as soon as I start Android Studio.

So far, the best solution I have found is to have a shortcut on the desk top, see this question: [How to start an Android virtual device without seeing emulator.exe window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313025/how-to-start-an-android-virtual-device-without-seeing-emulator-exe-window/30255738#30255738)